# Should I put "Postgraduate projects" on my resume?

Tags: resume, projects

I graduated with a BS in engineering about 2 years and have been looking for a job since. I've been having trouble finding one, but I've done lots of independent learning and projects on the side, such as learning new software, some woodworking skills, etc. Nothing big came out of them (I didn't start my own company or anything), but should I put these on my resume in the "experience and projects" section? I think a 2-year gap has been turning employers off, so I'd like something to fill that gap.

Comment: What course is "BS" - Marketing? - Perhaps put a link to your CV might help us to fathom out why 2 years of not getting a job. I hope you have had an interview or two in that time

Comment: BS stands for Bachelor of Science, in Mechanical Engineering. I've had several interviews but nothing panned out. A lot of my experience is in the biomedical field, but most of the jobs I'm applying for (and most of the jobs in NYC) are construction/MEP related. Some of the postgraduate learning of done was learning software and background knowledge related to this industry, but I've been including that on my cover letter instead of my resume

Comment: Surely BSc not BS. PS:Do not put things just in the covering letter. Sometimes they get lost and not linked to a CV. Sometimes the person doing the selection only get the CVs

Comment: @EdHeal In the US it is called BS for Bachelor of Science and is very common (I don't know of any university that does not use it)

Comment: @EdHeal It's standard in the US to call both a Bachelor of Science and a Bachelor of the Arts a BS degree. BSc is rarely used, and usually signals someone who was educated outside the US.

Comment: @Frisbee - Come to Europe - There are hundreds of them

Comment: Just to clarify--I attended school in the US. A BSc isn't really common here; usually, BS stands for "Bachelor of Science", BE is "Bachelor of Engineering" (same thing as Bachelor of Science for engineering) and BA is "Bachelor of Arts"

Comment: @EdHeal "In the US"

Comment: @JoeStrazzere -Thanks for the advice. What phrase do you suggest I suggest I use. I know "postgraduate" makes it sound like I got an advanced degree, but I can't think of anything else. My main concern is to have something on my resume to show that I've been learning new skills while job hunting

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks for your advice Joe. I think that might work. If not, I could just stick to what I'm doing now and include that information in my cover letter

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at the 15 or so resumes I have on my desk, the word "Experience" seems to be often synonymous with "Employment". A number of these do have a separate "Projects" section, detailing exactly the sort of thing you list here. One even lists months/years, as follows:

> **Experience**
>
> *(list of employers)*
>
> **Projects**
>
> Project A (Aug 2012-July 2014)
> *(details details details)*
>
> Project B (Aug 2013-current)
> *(details details details)*

For a hiring manager, this is nice, as (1) it further highlights the applicants skills, as well as (2) demonstrates that he has interests/skills/passions beyond the ones he lists in the employment section. In all cases, though, they're relevant to the core skill set beingt advertised. Given that you're an engineer, projects such as woodworking should be listed in "interests" at the bottom of the resume (or not; many don't include an interests section at all).

Do note that you *do not* want to try to "cover up" the fact that you have a two-year employment gap in your resume. You can count on that coming up in an interview, and if it even just *appears* that you're trying to hide that in your resume you will end up looking shady and/or dishonest. Make sure its very clear that these are personal projects you worked for on your own time.

That said, if any of the projects turned into an income stream (e.g., launched a project that actually generates revenue), that should be listed in "Experience", as you can honestly say you work there to pay bills.